# Google Spreadsheet: vlookup with wildcards not in "search_key" but in "range"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

Just read couple of articles here, I am really close to find the solution, but now I can not solve one issue.

The problem:
I got one column with some texts which should be replaced by other text. Basically, where in a cell is "abc" (everywhere, so it can be "123abc456") it should be converted to ABC (not to 123ABC3456). And where is "bcd" -> BCD. and for this I got special table with replacements (this is the reason why I can not use IFS)

I tried to use vlookup

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fls86.png)

Wildcards are not working, google is adding wildcards to D1, not a2:a5 (in "search_key" but not to "range") So basically I am looking for "reversed vlookup" where I can use wildcards with range cells, not search_key.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) try,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$5)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$5, D2)), 1))
```

Translate to [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) if not directly transferrable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways to achieve what you're after, but this works...

```
VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A5,REGEXMATCH(D1,A2:A5)),A2:B5,2,FALSE)
```

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ReuxxOkNorQ4LME__iTqWnOqbbbEh-8RMt9X_B5drA/edit?usp=sharing)